How to switch to another page with a button click in streamlit
I have the following streamlit button:
    def _render_settings_button(self, column):
        with column.container():
            st.button(
                ":material/settings: Settings",
                key="settings_button",
                use_container_width=True,
                on_click=lambda: st.switch_page(st.session_state["pages"]["settings"])
            )

The problem is that when I click the button, I get this error:
Calling st.rerun() within a callback is a no-op.
How can I switch to another page using a st.button instead of a st.page_link (I want to use st.button because of the styling features).

I found I can achieve what I want by catching the return value from the button rendering instead of using a callback function:
    def _render_settings_button(self, column):
        with column.container():
            is_clicked = st.button(
                ":material/settings: Settings",
                key="settings_button",
                use_container_width=True,
            )
        
        if is_clicked:
            st.switch_page(st.session_state["pages"]["settings"])


Use st.session_state to keep track of the current page. Update this state when the button is clicked, and use it to show the right page.

You have to give an example, or something, man.
